# how to have no menuitem in submenu in tieredMenu primefaces?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

in tieredMenu of primefaces i dont want menuitem in my submenu thats what i have :

[image]

i want to go to "Gestion des Equipes" just by clicking on Equipes but i can add outcome to the submenu thats my code :

```
<p:tieredMenu style="width:170px;margin-left: 5px;color: red;">    
         <p:submenu label="Equipes"  styleClass="submenustyle"   >             
             <p:menuitem value="Gestion des Equipes"  ajax="false" outcome="###"  />  
        </p:submenu>
         <p:separator />   
        <p:submenu label="Outillages" styleClass="submenustyle" >  
             <p:menuitem value="Gestion des Outillages" ajax="false" outcome="###"  />  
        </p:submenu>
    </p:tieredMenu>
```

thats what i want i explain it edited by photoshop :

[image]

how can i do like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
 <p:submenu label="Equipes"  styleClass="submenustyle"   >             
             <p:menuitem value="Gestion des Equipes"  ajax="false" outcome="###"  />  
        </p:submenu>
```

To only use the menuitem:

```
  <p:menuitem value="Equipes"  ajax="false" outcome="###"  />
```